# Difference between select * into newtable and create table newtable AS

Tags: performance, postgresql

I am working with huge table which has 9 million records. I am trying to take  backup of the table.  As below.

**First Query**

```
Create table newtable1 as  select * from hugetable  ;
```

**Second Query**

```
Select * into newtable2  from hugetable  ;
```

Here first query seems to be quite fast. I want to know the functional difference and Why it is fast compare to second query?,  Which one is to be preferred?

Answer (score 5):

[Quote from the manual:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtableas.html)

> This command (`create table as`) is functionally similar to SELECT INTO, but it is preferred since it is less likely to be confused with other uses of the SELECT INTO syntax. Furthermore, CREATE TABLE AS offers a superset of the functionality offered by SELECT INTO.

So both do the same thing, but `CREATE TABLE AS` is part of the SQL standard (and thus works on other DBMS as well), whereas the `SELECT INTO` is non-standard. As the manuals says, you should prefer `CREATE TABLE AS` over the non-standard syntax.

Performance wise both are identical, the differences you see are probably related to caching or other activities on your system.